# Does a student coming to Canada for less than 6 months with a travel allowance need a work visa or study permit?

Tags: visa, working-visas, canada, student-visa

**Why I'm coming to Canada:**

I'm currently a fourth year undergraduate engineering student holding an **Indian passport**. I've been accepted for a 6-month **thesis** at Ecole Polytechnique, Montreal, **Quebec**. The thesis is an **academic requirement of my university**, and comprises the last semester of my undergraduate studies. My university requires me to do a thesis for **at least 4 months**, although **preferably 5 to 5-1/2 months** to get the most out of my thesis. My university has **no tie ups** with any Canadian universities.

**What benefits I'm being offered:**

My offer letter states that I will be provided a 5000$ allowance for flight tickets and accommodation (which I will have to arrange myself), and the *possibility* of a 3000$ scholarship, based on my performance during the first 3 months.

**What I've looked at so far:**

At present, I'm confused about whether I will require a work visa, a study permit, or neither. Since I'm not getting a stipend per se, as far as I can tell, I will not require a work visa, but I'm not very sure. Also, as per the Canadian Immigration and Citizenship website, it seems that a study permit will not be required for a short-term course (6 months or less). Does this mean that I require neither visa? If I require neither, then what type of visa would I require?

Comment: What do you mean by "tie ups"?

Comment: It sounds like you'll need a regular "visitor visa."  This is the same visa tourists use, but it is not specifically a tourist visa.

Comment: "tie up" = an official collaboration and/or student exchange program.

Comment: The best thing to do is call [CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/contacts/call.asp) and confirm 1 (888) 242-2100

Comment: What visa did you end up applying for? Maybe you could come back and answer your own question to help future users in the same situation?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this. I ended up taking a visitor visa, *and* registering as a part time student at the university. I'm unfortunately still unclear about whether it is possible to take a visitor visa alone, without registering as a part (/full) time student.

Answer (score 3):

2017 update: as provided by the individual who posed the question:

The situation was resolved satisfactorily by [making application to Canada as a tourist](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-how.asp), and being granted a visa which allows residence in Canada for up to a six-month stay from the day of entry. [Extension is permitted](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend-stay.asp) while in Canada, but must be applied for at least 30 days before the authorized end of stay.

In addition, he enrolled as a part-time student to fulfill the requirements of his home university.

> [You can study at any school in Canada without a study permit if](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/study-who.asp):
>
> - your course or program is for six months or less
> - your studies aren’t part of a longer program and
> - you will complete all your studies within the time we approved you to stay in Canada (usually six months after you enter).

Comment: "your studies aren’t part of a longer program". If you are studying in order to fulfil requirements of your home university then it sounds like they are part of a longer program.